# How do I escape SQL query's single quotes for query generated in javascript/jquery in cartodb database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I am using javascript/jquery to generate a sql query.
I have a sql query I'm generating and using inside a javascript/jquery script.

Something like this:

```
var storeName;
var query = "SELECT * FROM stores where storeName = '" + storeName + "';";
```

(`storeName` is generated through jquery when a user selects from html)

So when  `storeName`  is something like **"Jackson Deli"** the query runs just fine.

But then when `storeName` is **"Jackson's Deli"** it does not work and it seems to be because the apostrophe in **Jackson's** is treated like a closing quote.  I know I can escape a quote by doubling it if I was hard-coding the query... so

```
SELECT * FROM stores where storeName = 'Jackson''s Deli';
```

should work.  But I'm not hard-coding the query.  Instead it's being generated by user input and may or may not have an apostrophe in the name.  How would I go about escaping `'` this character in this case?  I would need it to work inside Javascript/jquery.

Would I need to write an if statement that looks for `'` in `storeName` and replaces it with `''` ??
Or is there another way to go about this?

EDIT:
Ouch!  Normally, yes, I realize the perils of generating a query on the client side.
So here's some more context.  I'm working with [cartodb](http://www.cartodb.com) and following their documentation.  Here's an example from their repo doing something similar to what I'm talking about (they have other examples too):

https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/layer_selector.html

You can't run a query in cartodb that lets you modify data in any way -- you can only run queries that let you retrieve data.  So I'm still thinking about what the best way to escape this quote character would be.

Comment: Holy SQL injection batman. Who or where did you ever learn to create dynamic SQL strings on the client?>!

Comment: Just curious, are you generating SQL queries on the client side? If anything, **THAT** takes SQL injection to a new level! The way to go about _that_ would be to **throw it as far as possible. Or even farther!**

Comment: I really hope you're doing this in Node or Rhino. If this is being executed from a browser, your DB is toast.

Comment: LOL @gvee that was the first thing I thought of.  Afterwards I noticed that 2 people had actually upvoted this insane question!

Comment: @gvee I know that number `327` by heart now just from it being used as an answer on SO.

Comment: Thanks all - I guess I was expecting a bit of the reaction I got... please see my edit as I was just following documentation for the cartodb platform.

Comment: I love how everyone flipped out about the security issue in his software and TOTALLY ignored the actual question. Classic S.O.

Answer (score 5):

### **DO NOT GENERATE SQL ON THE CLIENT SIDE... EVER**

That being said, if you are going to use a dynamic query, you are best off escaping the user input and binding it to a prepared statement on the server side.

If you post more details about which database (MySQL, Postgres, etc.) and what language you are using for server processing- you will get better answers.

Yes... I am fully aware this doesn't answer the question. Nobody should be creating code this way though.

**Edit:** Made the warning bigger for emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

I see others have answered but I wanted to approach this question from a few angles.

The question you're asking is a good one.  You recognize that the SQL doesn't work with single quotes.  You realize that something needs to be escaped.  These are a good starting point for a few considerations that will hopefully help you to architect software in a secure and maintainable way.

1. **Never directly execute client code/content** - Generating SQL or any kind of code/instructions (javascript, bytecode, compiled code) from a client is always a poor idea because it breaks a few critical concepts.

   - It's hard to maintain because you cannot control the input fully.  Sure you could escape the SQL but that doesn't fix both strange case scenarios where you have other characters you didn't account for.
   - **It isn't secure** - Your relationship to variables, inputs, CGI params, file contents, database fields whose values came from the aforementioned list, or just about anything that came from a remote system, remote user cannot **ever** be trusted.  Always check, sanitize and validate inputs.  I can open the source to your page, see where you add a check for single quotes and change that and then execute the code to delete your records, have it email if certain stored procedures are available, run code on the SQL backend, drop databases (assuming the query runs under appropriate privileges.)
   - It blends/blurs the lines between client input/display and business logic.  Research MVC, n-Tier development and other concepts for an introduction to the concepts of separating your business logic from display/inputs.  This is critical not only for scalability and performance but also to reduce the change of issues such as this from causing critical security flaws.
2. **Approach your software development from the bad-guys perspective** - Instead of "How can I escape this string to make it work." try "How can I bypass the escape on this page to allow me to delete records, view things I should, etc.
3. **Don't feel bad because the approach is wrong**,learn from it.  I see alot of comments about how you should never ever do this (and they're right) but many of us learned this lesson the hard way.  We laugh at [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) because we've all written or had to support code that did this.  The key is to understand the underpinning of why it's a bad idea and then use that in designing software.  Welcome to the school of hard knocks.  We're all graduates and thankfully you could learn from our comments rather than when somebody tinkers and corrupts, deletes or infiltrates your database and application.

To get you started on this journey may I suggest reading the following:
[SQL Injections Explained](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html)

And as an added bonus [XSS](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/)  E.g. escaping OUTPUT that originated from an external system or person.  for example a comment entry that contains `Hi!!! <script>alert('Thanks to this site not escaping this output I get to run this code under your login.  Thanks for the 4000 crates of free tshirts you just ordered for me');</script> how are you???` so that when you output it you get

```
Comments:Hi!!! <script>alert('Thanks to this site not escaping this output I get to run this code under your login.  Thanks for the 4000 crates of free tshirts you just ordered for me');</script> how are you???
```

Which is "valid" HTML and the browser will execute it.

**Final thoughts** - Adopt the motto [Trust but Verify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify) and you'll be OK

Answer (score 2):

FYI, CartoDB does not allow you to execute a query that changes something in the table, it's read-only.

Comment: Right... which is why I thought it would be OK.  I guess I should have originally stated I was working with cartodb.  So then I do still have the issue of how to escape the apostrophe / single quote character.

Comment: @maneesha - While you may not be able to incorrectly update/delete/alter the data you may still run/exec something else (not sure.) and at the very least have the ability to see other data you shouldn't (e.g. usernames, password hashes, etc)

Comment: thx.  cartodb's own documentation guides users to do this, creating map layers through SQL queries generated by jquery events.  See an example in my edits to my original question.  They do not have a method for escaping these kinds of characters which is really all my original question was about.

Answer (score 0):

Send data to your server first, then escape all chars that need to be escaped with addslashes() command (provided that you are using PHP).

[addslashes() command on PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

After you are done with eascaping characters, you can send your data to cartoDB using their API and your API key.

Answer (score -1):

cartoDB does provide insert/update/delete tasks through its SQL API.  See this link:

http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/sql-api.html

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow. Please note your answer does not reply the question, it should explain *how to escape single quotes on an SQL string*